# How to add filter expressions to a list in Google Analytics Data API (GA4) using the Ruby client?

Tags: ruby, google-analytics-4

I'm using the `google-analytics-data` gem to query the GA4 API in a ruby client.

When I attempt to add an array of filter expressions to a filter expression list I get an error on line 161:

```
analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list.expressions = analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list_expressions

method_missing': Expected repeated field array
```

Here is my code

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby

require 'google-analytics-data'

module GoogleAnalyticsObjects

    def self.get_analytics_data( analytics:,
                                 start_date:,
                                 end_date:,
                                 metrics:,
                                 dimensions:, 
                                 order_bys: [] )
                                 
                          
      analytics_date_range_object = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::DateRange.new
      analytics_date_range_object.start_date = start_date
      analytics_date_range_object.end_date = end_date
  
     
      report_request_object_metrics = []
  
      metrics.each { |metric|
        
      analytics_metric_object = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Metric.new
      analytics_metric_object.name = metric 
      
      report_request_object_metrics.push(analytics_metric_object) } 
  
      unless dimensions.empty?
  
        report_request_object_dimensions = []
  
        dimensions.each { |dimension|
          analytics_dimension_object = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Dimension.new
          analytics_dimension_object.name = dimension
          report_request_object_dimensions.push(analytics_dimension_object) }
      end       

      unless order_bys.empty?
  
        report_request_object_order_bys = []
  
        order_bys.each { |orderby|
          analytics_orderby_object = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::OrderBy.new 

          analytics_orderby_object.field_name = orderby
          analytics_orderby_object.sort_order = 'DESCENDING'
          report_request_object_order_bys.push(analytics_orderby_object)}
      end
      
      ################
      analytics_request_object_filter_expression = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::FilterExpression.new    
      ################

      ################
      analytics_request_object_filter_expression_campaign = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::FilterExpression.new  
      ################
      
      ################
      analytics_request_object_filter_campaign = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter.new

      analytics_request_object_filter_campaign.field_name = 'campaign'

      analytics_request_object_filter_campaign_string_filter = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter::StringFilter.new

      analytics_request_object_filter_campaign_string_filter.case_sensitive = false

      analytics_request_object_filter_campaign_string_filter.value = '(not set)'

      analytics_request_object_filter_campaign_string_filter.match_type = 'EXACT'

      analytics_request_object_filter_campaign.string_filter = analytics_request_object_filter_campaign_string_filter 
     
      analytics_request_object_filter_expression_campaign.filter = analytics_request_object_filter_campaign # this filter expression gets added to the top level filter expression
      
      puts 
      puts 'not expression filter expression'
      puts analytics_request_object_filter_expression_campaign.inspect
      ###############

      ###############
      analytics_request_object_filter_expression.not_expression = analytics_request_object_filter_expression_campaign  # here
      ###############    

      puts
      puts 'top level filter expression after not expression added'
      puts analytics_request_object_filter_expression.inspect

      ###############
      analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::FilterExpressionList.new # gets added to the top level filter expression list
      ###############
            
      ###############
      analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list_expressions = [] # array to hold top level filter expression and group filter expressions
      ###############
   
      ###############
      analytics_request_object_filter_expression_source_medium = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::FilterExpression.new
  
      analytics_request_object_filter_source_medium = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter.new

      analytics_request_object_filter_source_medium.field_name = 'sourceMedium'

      analytics_request_object_filter_source_medium_string_filter = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter::StringFilter.new

      analytics_request_object_filter_source_medium_string_filter.case_sensitive = false

      analytics_request_object_filter_source_medium_string_filter.match_type = 'EXACT'

      analytics_request_object_filter_source_medium_string_filter.value = 'aomestring'

      analytics_request_object_filter_source_medium.string_filter = analytics_request_object_filter_source_medium_string_filter 

      analytics_request_object_filter_expression_source_medium.filter = analytics_request_object_filter_source_medium  

      puts
      puts 'sourceMedium filter expression'
      puts analytics_request_object_filter_expression_source_medium.inspect
      ##############

      ##############
      analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list_expressions.push(analytics_request_object_filter_expression_source_medium)  # add to array 
      ##############


      ##############
      analytics_request_object_filter_expression_transactions = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::FilterExpression.new

      analytics_request_object_filter_transactions = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter.new

      analytics_request_object_filter_transactions.field_name = 'transactions'
      
      analytics_request_object_filter_transactions_numeric_filter = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter::NumericFilter.new

      analytics_request_object_filter_transactions_numeric_filter.operation = 'GREATER_THAN'

      analytics_request_object_filter_transactions_numeric_value = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::NumericValue.new

      analytics_request_object_filter_transactions_numeric_value.int64_value = 0

      analytics_request_object_filter_transactions_numeric_filter.value = analytics_request_object_filter_transactions_numeric_value

      analytics_request_object_filter_transactions.numeric_filter = analytics_request_object_filter_transactions_numeric_filter 

      analytics_request_object_filter_expression_transactions.filter = analytics_request_object_filter_transactions

      puts
      puts 'transactions filter expression'
      puts analytics_request_object_filter_expression_transactions.inspect
      #############

      #############
      analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list_expressions.push(analytics_request_object_filter_expression_transactions) # add to array
      #############

      puts
      puts 'array of and group expressions'
      puts analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list_expressions.inspect
      #############   

      analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list.expressions = analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list_expressions

      puts
      puts 'and group expressions list final'
      puts analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list.inspect
      #############

      #############
      #analytics_request_object_filter_expression.and_group = analytics_request_object_filter_expression_and_group   
      analytics_request_object_filter_expression.and_group = analytics_request_object_filter_expressions_list

      puts
      puts 'top level filter expression'
      puts analytics_request_object_filter_expression.inspect
      #############

      report_request_object = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::RunReportRequest.new(
        property: "properties/#{ANALYTICS_PROPERTY_ID}",
        metrics: report_request_object_metrics,
        dimensions: report_request_object_dimensions,
        order_bys: report_request_object_order_bys,
        date_ranges: [analytics_date_range_object],
        dimension_filter: analytics_request_object_filter_expression) 

      response = analytics.run_report(report_request_object)

    end
  
end # module
```

edit. This is the output from the above code

```
not expression filter expression. This filter expression attaches to the not expression of the top level filter expression 
<Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::FilterExpression: 
    filter: <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter: 
        field_name: "campaign", 
        string_filter: <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter::StringFilter: 
        match_type: :EXACT, 
        value: "(not set)", 
        case_sensitive: false>>>

top level filter expression after not expression added
<Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::FilterExpression: 
    not_expression: 
        <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::FilterExpression: 
            filter: <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter: 
            field_name: "campaign", 
            string_filter: <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter::StringFilter: 
                match_type: :EXACT, 
                value: "(not set)", 
                case_sensitive: false>>>>

Above is a singleton filter expression.

sourceMedium filter expression. First element of the and group
<Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::FilterExpression: 
    filter: <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter: 
        field_name: "sourceMedium", 
        string_filter: <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter::StringFilter: 
            match_type: :EXACT, 
            value: "somestring", 
            case_sensitive: false>>>

transactions filter expression. Second element of the and group
<Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::FilterExpression: 
    filter: <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter: 
        field_name: "transactions", 
        numeric_filter: <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter::NumericFilter: 
            operation: :GREATER_THAN, 
            value: <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::NumericValue: int64_value: 0>>>>

Array of and group expressions. Error occurs adding this array to top level filter and group

"google_analytics_objects.rb:173:in `method_missing': Expected repeated field array"

[
    <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::FilterExpression: 
        filter: <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter: 
            field_name: "sourceMedium", 
            string_filter: <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter::StringFilter: 
                match_type: :EXACT, 
                value: "somestring", 
                case_sensitive: false>>>, 
                
    <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::FilterExpression: 
        filter: <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter: 
            field_name: "transactions", 
            numeric_filter: <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Filter::NumericFilter: 
                operation: :GREATER_THAN, 
                value: <Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::NumericValue: int64_value: 0>>>>
]

API doc [https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/reference/google-analytics-data-v1beta/latest/Google-Analytics-Data-V1beta-FilterExpression][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

That error reads like gRPC barfing because it received something else when it expected an array, or it received an array but something in the array is not the kind of repeated object it's expecting.

Is the argument passed to `push` in your code ever an array? If so, you're going to need to prefix it with a splat (`*`) to spread the elements out into individual arguments. If the protobuf for that expressions assignment is expecting a message with a definition along the lines of `repeated Expression expressions = 1;` and then it receives an array object where one of the elements is a whole other array of elements, that would cause an error like that. The [expressions=(value)](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/reference/google-analytics-data-v1beta/latest/Google-Analytics-Data-V1beta-FilterExpressionList) assignment method documentation indicates that it's expecting an array of FilterExpression objects and it looks like your code is doing that, but some of the variable names in your code don't track so I'm going to make some assumptions...

The initialization of `analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list` is missing, but I'm assuming it's initialized as a `Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::FilterExpressionList`.

I think this is the actual problem line:

```rb
analytics_request_object_filter_expression_and_group.push(analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list)
```

Assuming it has a typo and the second-to-last underscore should be a period, this line would be appending an entire ExpressionList (as a single element) to the ExpressionList returned by the `and_group` accessor method (which would cause the error you're getting). I'd hazard a guess that this will work:

```rb
analytics_request_object_filter_expression.and_group.push(
  *analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list
)
```

However, the API defines assignment and accessor methods for `and_group` but does not define an append method... while calling `#push` on the list returned by the accessor method will technically work to add new elements, it is using ruby's variable handling to hack around how the object is designed to be interacted with. The `and_group` on that object should also already be empty based on what you've provided, so it would be better practice to just pass the list to the `and_group=` assignment method:

```rb
# If you don't need to merge the list into the existing `and_group` list:
analytics_request_object_filter_expression.and_group = analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list
```

Recommend running your code line-by-line in a console and taking a close look at your objects.

Comment: I have edited my code to reflect what I understand are the changes you suggest. It Includes my complete code and the output.

Comment: Put a binding in it and play with it... what happens if you set expressions to an empty array or an array containing one of your filter expressions? It's also possible there's a bug in the assignment method where it's not properly copying the array into a RepeatedExpression object. See how the error changes when you try to pass different input to `expressions=`

Comment: It looks like there is also a typo in `analytics_request_object_filter_expressions_list`; the rest of your code is referring to it as `analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list` ('expression' should be singular)

Comment: The typo is after the error. It would be another error

Comment: Adding an empty array didn't work, same error. `analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list.expressions = [] # analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list_expressions`

Comment: It's unclear if a single element array might work, or if no form of array works; if no form of array works, it could be a bug with converting the array to a RepeatedExpression (https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/7161) because they are not the same object. You should look at what it returns when you call `analytics_request_object_filter_expression_list.expressions`. It is also a beta library, so if you can't isolate what it needs through trial and error then check their developer resources and file a bug ticket if needed: https://developers.google.com/analytics/help/

Comment: I did actually try a single element array with each of the two filter expressions and it still didn't work. I'm going to try this wrapper https://github.com/dailytics/google_analytics_v4_api